# Explict generic type in function by default replace this type to dynamic inside

Tags: dart

Why explict generic type in function by default replace this type to dynamic inside?

example:

```dart
class Boo {
  void displayType<int>() {
    print('type int to string: $int');
    print('type string to string: $String');
  }
}

main() {
  final boo = Boo();
  boo.displayType();
}
```

output:

```
type int to string: dynamic
type string to string: String
```

its bug?

Comment: Please check my answer, there is a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

name of generic can be existing type. So if tell any type in function, inside `int` can be any another type

```dart
main() {
  final boo = Boo();
  boo.displayType<Boo>();
}
```

```
type int to string: Boo
type string to string: String
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `<int>` is not an `int` data type but a name of generic datatype to be passed into function.

```
void displayType<int>() {
    print('type int to string: $int');
    print('type string to string: $String');
  }
```

Compliler builds priorities from global to local. That means - it will prioritize local variables, arguments, generic types more than global ones. For example:

```
int number = 2;
void someFunc(){
  //local variables are in higher priorities inside their closures
  int number = 3;
  //will print 3
  print(number);
}
```

You definded generic type as `<int>` - compiler takes it as a priority in assgning and usage operations above the actual data type named `int`. Knowing this - do not be confused and make generic types consisting of 1 letter as usually it is done in many documentations.

```
   void displayType<T>() {
    //now it prints int
    print('type int to string: $int');
    //will print dynamic
    print('type generic to string: $T');
    print('type string to string: $String');
  }
  main() {
  final boo = Boo();
  boo.displayType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You function declaration

```dart
  void displayType<int>() {
    print('type int to string: $int');
    print('type string to string: $String');
  }
```

introduces a generic function with a type parameter named `int`.
It's exactly the same as

```dart
  void displayType<T>() {
    print('type int to string: $T');
    print('type string to string: $String');
  }
```

except that the type parameter is named `int`, which also shadows the declaration of `int` normally imported from `dart:core`.

When you then call that method without a type argument, as

```dart
boo.displayType();
```

the type argument `T`/`int` (name doesn't matter) is inferred by using the bound of the type parameter (because there are no method arguments to infer a type from either). It has no bound given, so it defaults to `dynamic`.

It's *not at all clear* what you are trying to do.

If you wanted a type parameter bounded by `int`, you can write

```dart
  void displayType<T extends int>() {
    print('type T to string: $T');
    print('type int to string: $int');
    print('type string to string: $String');
  }
```

If you are trying to override a superclass method which is also generic, to not be generic, you *can't do that*. The override must have the same type parameters with the same bounds as the superclass, otherwise the override is invalid.